# Flask not autoreloading inside container when code changes in bind mount directory

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose

I have a Dockerfile which I am using to create a container for a Flask application. It is in a subdirectory, since I have multiple Dockerfiles and docker-compose files and I didn't like them cluttering up the root of the project.

When developing locally, I want use a Docker [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to mount the local directory into the container, overlaying an existing directory. This will allow Flask to notice file changes and reload the development server without me needing to restart the Docker containers.

I am running the container with this command:

```bash
docker-compose -p myproject -f docker/docker-compose.dev.yml up
```

**The bind mount was working** with this setup:

*docker/Dockerfile.dev*

```docker
# setup...

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app # To allow the container to start successfully, before the bind mount is mounted
```

*docker/docker-compose.dev.yml*

```yaml
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ..:/app
    // And a bunch of other setup stuff and services
```

I followed [this helpful tutorial](https://sourcery.ai/blog/python-docker/) to help slim down my container, and adopt Pipenv. It recommended a slightly different setup, where my container creates a user instead of running everything as root. So I now have this **which is failing:**

*docker/Dockerfile.dev*

```docker
# setup...

RUN useradd --create-home appuser
WORKDIR /home/appuser
USER appuser

COPY . .
```

*docker/docker-compose.dev.yml*

```yaml
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ..:/home/appuser
    // And a bunch of other setup stuff and services
```

While the app launches successfully because I've copied everything into place with the `COPY` command, the server doesn't reload when I change files in the host directory. When I open a shell using this command:

```
docker run --env-file .env --entrypoint bash --network flasknetwork -v $(PWD):/home/appuser -ti api
```

Then of course the bind mount appears as expected, shadowing `appuser`'s home directory in the container.

I don't understand what's different between these two setups. How can I get the bind mount working again when the container is launched using `docker-compose`?

Comment: Can you use a host-based Python virtual environment for day-to-day development, instead of trying to convince Docker to be a live-reloading environment?

Comment: Not using Docker means that developers need to set up and run Postgres (including various extensions) on their systems. Devs would also need to run Redis and worker processes manually. So while it's possible, Docker allows for a much simpler dev experience. Fortunately, I got it working again!

Comment: You can use Docker for all of those infrastructure parts, but use a virtual environment for the application proper.  `docker-compose up -d postgres redis` or something like that would start the specific dependencies, and then you can configure your host-based application to point at their published `ports:`.

Comment: That would work, yes. Is there a benefit to requiring this extra step vs the current setup, where you just do `docker-compose up` and you're away?

Comment: You'll have an actual local development environment; you don't need to depend on Docker's volume mounting mechanism to correctly sync things from the host filesystem into the container (that is, it avoids the problem in the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem wasn't the bind mount after all. I used `docker inspect api` and discovered that the mount was working as expected:

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "bind",
        "Source": "/Users/myuser/src/project",
        "Destination": "/home/appuser",
        "Mode": "rw",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    }
],
```

So I looked up [Flask autoreloading](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#debug-mode), and remembered that it only works when `FLASK_ENV` is set to `development`. This setting had gotten removed as I was moving things around, and I hadn't added it back. So the app was running in production mode, and thus was not autoreloading.